# Play 2.0, get active route/url/Call?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am creating a paginator for my application.

I can't figure how to get current route / tell if the page / "Call" is active.

The code in index.scala.html

```
@if(page.getTotalPageCount() > 0){
<div class="pagination">
    <ul>
    @for(i <- 0 to page.getTotalPageCount()-1){
        <li@if(@routes.NewsHandler.index(i) == ?){ class="active"}><a href="@routes.NewsHandler.index(i)">@(i+1)</a></li>
    }
    </ul>
</div>
}
```

So basically.

```
if(@routes.NewsHandler.index(i) == ?){ class="active"}
```

Any ideas?

EDIT, i found a working solution:

```
@if(request().path().toString().equals(routes.NewsHandler.index(i).toString())){ class="active"}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is currently no standard way to know the current `Handler` for a request.